# ActiveRecord includes. Specify included columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have model Profile. Profile has_one User. User model has field email. When I call

```
Profile.some_scope.includes(:user)
```

it calls

```
SELECT users.* FROM users WHERE users.id IN (some ids)
```

But my User model has many fields that I am not using in rendering. Is it possible to load only emails from users? So, SQL should look like

```
SELECT users.email FROM users WHERE users.id IN (some ids)
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Rails doesn't have the facility to pass the options for **include** query. But we can pass these params with the **association declaration** under the model.

For your scenario, you need to create a new association with users model under the profile model, like below

```
belongs_to :user_only_fetch_email, :select => "users.id, users.email", :class_name => "User"
```

I just created one more association but it points to User model only. So your query will be,

```
Profile.includes(:user_only_fetch_email)
```

or

```
Profile.includes(:user_only_fetch_email).find(some_profile_ids)
```

Comment: The foreign_key option must be added when using select.

From the manual: guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference

4.1.3.4 select

The select method lets you override the SQL SELECT clause that is used to retrieve data about the associated object. By default, Rails retrieves all columns.

If you use the select method on a belongs_to association, you should also set the :foreign_key option to guarantee the correct results.

Comment: Had to change the syntax a bit to get it to work (Rails 4):
`belongs_to :user_only_fetch_email, -> {select('users.id, users.email')}, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'`

Comment: I can't get this to work on Rails 3 unfortunately. I added foreign key as well, but when running the query, it does not give a error, but also does not load the association + fields. EDIT: never mind, I needed the `:has_one` assocation instead of the `:belongs_to` , now it works perfectly!

Answer (score 17):

If you want to select specific attributes, you should use [`joins`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.8/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/joins) rather than `includes`.

From this [asciicast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins?view=asciicast):

> the include option doesn’t really work with the select option as we don’t have control over how the first part of the SELECT statement is generated. If you need control over the fields in the SELECT then you should use joins over include.

Using `joins`:

```
Profile.some_scope.joins(:users).select("users.email")
```

Comment: I'm not sure that answers the question, but it's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: this is true, but :joins doesn't accomplish the magical eager-loading of associations that :includes does.

Comment: You can use :includes but you need to use :references as well to specify which tables you reference in your where clause

Comment: Using includes with references brings you back to the initial problem of this post.

Answer (score 12):

You need extra belongs to in the model.

For simple association:

```
belongs_to :user_restricted, -> { select(:id, :email) }, class_name: 'User'
```

For Polymorphic association (for example, `:commentable`):

```
belongs_to :commentable_restricted, -> { select(:id, :title) }, polymorphic: true, foreign_type: :commentable_type, foreign_key: :commentable_id
```

You can choose whatever `belongs_to` name you want. For the examples given above, you can use them like `Article.featured.includes(:user_restricted)`, `Comment.recent.includes(:commentable_restricted)` etc.

Answer (score 5):

Rails does not support to select specific columns when `includes`. You know ,it's just `lazy load`.

It use the [ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb#L92) module to load the associated data before data actually using. By the [method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/preloader.rb#L92):

```
def preload(records, associations, preload_scope = nil)
    records = Array.wrap(records).compact

    if records.empty?
      []
    else
      records.uniq!
      Array.wrap(associations).flat_map { |association|
        preloaders_on association, records, preload_scope
      }
    end
 end
```

`preload_scope` the third params of `preload`, is a way to select specify columns. **But can't lazy load anymore**.

#### At Rails 5.1.6

```
relation = Profile.where(id: [1,2,3])
user_columns = {:select=>[:updated_at, :id, :name]}
preloader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
preloader.preload(relation, :user, user_columns)
```

It will select the specify columns you passed in. But, it just for single association. You need create a patch for `ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader` to support loading multiple complex associations at once.

[Here is a example for patch](https://github.com/EarlyZhao/selectable_column_sample/blob/master/config/initializers/preloader_patch.rb)

[The way to use it, example](https://github.com/EarlyZhao/selectable_column_sample/blob/master/app/services/selectable_column/test.rb)

Comment: I like this solution, as it prevent littering the code with a belongs_to in an unrelated place. Note that in Rails 6 `preload_scope` changed to be an Active record Relation instead of a Hash, so in the above example it would become: `user_columns = User.select(:updated_at, :id, :name)`

Answer (score 2):

I wanted that functionality myself,so please use it.
Include this method in your class

#ACCEPTS args in string format "ASSOCIATION_NAME:COLUMN_NAME-COLUMN_NAME"

```
def self.includes_with_select(*m)
    association_arr = []
    m.each do |part|
      parts = part.split(':')
      association = parts[0].to_sym
      select_columns = parts[1].split('-')
      association_macro = (self.reflect_on_association(association).macro)
      association_arr << association.to_sym
      class_name = self.reflect_on_association(association).class_name 
      self.send(association_macro, association, -> {select *select_columns}, class_name: "#{class_name.to_sym}")
    end
    self.includes(*association_arr)
  end
```

And you will be able to call like: `Contract.includes_with_select('user:id-name-status', 'confirmation:confirmed-id')`, and it will select those specified columns.

Comment: well for some reason for me there are still all selected 

        @articles = @articles.includes_with_select("social_post:followers")

but then 

"social_posts"."message" AS t3_r7, "social_posts"."sentiment" AS t3_r8, "social_posts"."url" AS t3_r9

appears in the sql

Answer (score 0):

Using Mohanaj's example, you can do this:

```
belongs_to :user_only_fetch_email, -> { select [:id, :email] }, :class_name => "User"
```