# ActiveRecord Slow Object Instantiation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I maintain a website of events taking place in my city.

My website homepage is a 5-days calendar with all the events taking place from today to 4 days in the future.

I have done quite a good job with my "ActiveRecord" code as I have around **~120ms spent in MySQL** (double checked with RackMiniProfiler) to load ~200-300 events.

However my response time is very slow (1.5s - 2s).

**Most time is spent in instantiation of AR's objects from my queries**

Using ObjectSpace, I see that **~6k AR::Base objects are instantiated** for +300 events that are displayed.

The reason why there are so many objects is that my **Event** model has many associated models (e.g. venue, occurrences, categories, etc...), all of which contain bits of information I need to show.

As expected, profiling proved ActiveRecord's object instantiation as the most consuming task during the request.

I am not experienced enough in neither ActiveRecord nor its performance.

Is such speed expected or should my objects be instantiated much faster?

Should I move away from AR and use **simple ruby hashes**?

Is this the **Rails standard** when my data model is too complex?

**========= UPDATE 1 =========**

This [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/3VkfGS1Y) contains the service class I use to load the events for a single day in the calendar.
I hope it's understandable, I did not have time to properly document it since it's still a work in progress to improve performance.

**========= UPDATE 2 =========**

Loading all these objects has another drawback: it causes **GC runs** while the page is being rendered, adding ~100ms after every *n* events are rendered, which becomes a total overhead of ~500ms.

To give you an idea of how much data I'm loading (sadly 99% of it is needed), **if I dump to JSON I get a 47K file**.

**========= UPDATE 3 =========**

As mentioned by @TheSuper, even though it does not improve AR's performance, fragment caching is indeed my friend as I'm rendering quite the amount of data while under GC runs. Applying **fragment caching** yielded a 1-1.2s improvement, which is HUGE.

However I still cannot overcome the 600ms wall of AR.
A possible improvement are *"selective includes"* discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400860/activerecord-includes-specify-included-columns), for the few cases where I need a small portion of the attributes of an included model, but this is ugly and inflexible.

Comment: Caching is your friend here. Rails has some excellent guides on how to do it, and you'll see huge speedups.

Comment: some code would help.

Comment: @TheSuper thx for the quick reply. If I am not wrong, russian doll caching needs the AR object to have a timestamp for generating the cache-key, therefore wouldn't all the objects be instantiated anyway?

Comment: @neo I updated my answer. I believe the code to be too messy at the moment. In my place it 7PM, tomorrow I'll better document the class and update the pastebin

Comment: A quick test of one of my smaller models instantiates 6k of them in around .25 seconds.

Comment: @ABMagil your timings are very compatible with mine: a simple model takes 250ms and a more complex model (if I convert to json I get a 47K document) takes ~600-800ms

Comment: Garbage Collection has undergone quite a bit of change in the last few versions of ruby.  Which version are you using?

Comment: Also, how could you possibly need all that data _at once_?  Is it possible to significantly increase the ajaxiness of your app and reduce the initial payload?

Comment: @ABMagil I have thought about that for quite some time, but because of some problems specific to calendars I did not find a way. I would love to discuss this with you, but I believe that another medium should be used as it would be off-topic for this question.