# Optimize associated queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, optimization, query-optimization

Lets take the following example. We have two models with this association

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user  
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

So as you know, we can do the following:

```
<%= @post.title %>
<%= @post.user.name %>
etc etc
```

This association usually generates the following queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `post`.`id` = 1;
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user`.`id` = 15; # from @post.user
```

Now if I want to **select some specific fields** (lets assume for a moment there's no association) when listing all posts or show just a single one, I do something like this:

```
@posts = Post.select("id, title, slug, created_at").all()
# or
@post = Post.select("id, title, slug, created_at").find(1)
```

In case of association how can I select specific fields for the associated query? In other words instead of having

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` IN ( user IDs here )
```

to have

```
SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `users`
SELECT `id`, `user_id`, `title`, `slug` FROM `posts` WHERE `user_id` IN ( user IDs here )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When you retrieve a single Post** restricting it's attributes in `select` clause, it behaves like any other Post, but in order to have access to the User it should have the `user_id` attribute selected.

```
@post = Post.select("id").first
# this post doesn't know about it's user since it has no user_id attribute
@post.user # => nil

@post = Post.select("id", "user_id").first
# this post has a user
@post.user # => #<User...>
```

**When you retrieve a list of posts** you should solve the '*n+1 queries problem*'. You can read about it here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html (13 Eager Loading Associations)

You can use `includes` for eager loading associations:

```
@posts = Post.includes(:user)

@posts.each do |post|
  post.user # this will not make an extra DB query since users are already eager loaded
end
```

Or if you don't need to instantiate users and want just get specific attributes, the better solution is to `join` with users and take attributes that you need

```
@posts = Post.joins(:user).select("posts.id", "posts.title", "users.name AS user_name")

@posts.each do |post|
  post.user_name # each post now has `user_name` attribute
end
```

**Edited**

As far as I know using `includes` will ignore `select`. You can't use `select` here to specify which attributes of a Post or a User you need. The whole Post will be retrieved and the whole Users will be eager loaded. However, there is a way to restrict user's loading attributes by specifying them in `belongs_to` association. There is a similar question about this: [ActiveRecord includes. Specify included columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12400860/activerecord-includes-specify-included-columns)

Also, keep in mind, that `Post.joins(:user)` will not return posts that have no user. So, if it is possible and you need all posts use `.left_outer_joins` instead.

```
# works in Rails 5
Post.left_outer_joins(:user).select(...)
```

Comment: In my example I have this code `@posts = Post.select("id, user_id, title, slug").includes(:user)` .. So, if I understand correct in both answers, in order to select specific fields from `users` (such as only id and name) I should use `joins` instead of `includes` ??

Comment: I don't completely understand your question. I added some extra explanation to my answer. Use `joins` if you don't need a User instance for each Post (post.user), but only Post instances with some attributes that belong to their users. Use `includes` when you need not just user's attributes, but a user instance in order to use logic from User model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer below link about association

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html

Comment: I did an update on my queries.. basically I wand to use `select` with `includes` on Rails 4

Comment: you can use like  `Post.includes(:user).select("posts.id, posts.title, users.name AS user_name")`