# add includes + select into query + ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How can I write this query in Ruby on Rails to select `includes` model attributes like:
`Post.includes(:comment).select(:name, :title, :comments => [:email, :text])`

Comment: This approach should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12403327/5448461

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveRecord#select` doesn't support hashes as arguments, but you could use syntax like this:

`Post.joins(:comment).select(:name, :title).merge(Comment.select(:email, :text))`

But keep in mind that if Post has 3 comments it will return 3 instances of Post each with different comment data.